# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting after installation

Tags: boot, uefi, vaio

I have a Vaio Pro and had Ubuntu 13.10 with EFI boot on it which worked fine until I did something wrong. What I did:

- reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04
- run boot-repair
- create the EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi file on the EDI partition

but I still can't boot.

[Here is my boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7837592/).

Comment: As Volker said, please be specific with your title.

Comment: Are you having problems booting into Ubuntu or Windows 8 now?

Comment: Hi mchid  

Actually, I only have ubuntu, its not a dual boot.
I have exactly the same configuration with the 13.10 version which booted correctly.
The only difference is that I have a partition for the home

* EFI partition (300MB)
* ext4 partition for / (60Go)
* ext4 partition for /home (190Go)
* swap partition (8Go)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed Ubuntu 14.04 in BIOS mode, but your previous installation was in EFI mode. Your Boot Repair log is odd, so I suspect some other weirdness, too -- maybe you manually converted the disk from GPT to MBR form, for instance.

In any event, if you have no user data on the disk, or if you've got good backups of your user data, I recommend you start again, but this time, read a *good* guide on installing on an EFI-based system. ([Sturgeon's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) applies to guides to EFI-based installation, with a vengeance!) Two sites with good information are:

- [My page on EFI-mode installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

You could do a BIOS-mode installation, but I don't know of a good site that describes how to ensure that's what you're doing.

If you have user data that's not backed up and you don't want to do a backup-restore dance, try this:

1. Back up your user data. The odds of your losing it if you fail to do this are just too high.
2. Download and prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Launch `gdisk` on the disk. Change the type code of partition #1 to EF00 and then save your changes (via `w`).
4. Insert the rEFInd media in the computer and reboot to rEFInd. (You may need to use your firmware's built-in boot manager to select the rEFInd medium.)
5. Using rEFInd, boot Ubuntu. (There will probably be several Ubuntu or Linux options. Some might not work. Don't worry about that.)
6. In Ubuntu, type `sudo mkdir /boot/efi && sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`, then delete the `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft` directory tree. Since you don't have a Windows installation, the presence of the Windows boot loader on your ESP (`/dev/sda1`) is pointless and will simply clutter your boot manager menu.
7. In Ubuntu, do one of two things:

   - Re-install GRUB. The easiest way to do this is via Boot Repair, but you can use the `grub-install` command if you prefer.
   - Install the Debian-package version of rEFInd.

There are alternative ways to achieve the same results. For instance, your computer *might* boot to Ubuntu without rEFInd once you've converted the disk to GPT form, but that's not certain. You could also try doing it without an MBR-to-GPT conversion, although that's very unusual for an EFI installation and isn't guaranteed to work.

It's also probably possible to get the system booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, which is (mostly) how it's set up now; but your description provides no clue as to what it's actually doing, so it's hard to say what's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I'll try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu works well now.

Here is what I did:

1. Disable secure boot (didn't do it the first time)
2. Standard install (no customization) from live USB
3. Run boot repair + create dir /boot/efi/ and renamed grubx64.efi into bootx64.efi
4. At reboot, I got the grub but then fall into the initramfs prompt
5. I reboot and chose the recovery mode, check the system up and got into the session screen
6. I updated the system
7. At the next reboot, it tooks a long time but finaly launch the session screen.

I didn't try to reboot for now...

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is old but I landed as the result of a search.  Perhaps this will help someone else:

My solution to this problem (though I'm sure my repair logs may be different) was to burn my .iso to CD or USB with software that was not from Pendrive.  I gave LiLi USB installer a shot and it worked.

The moral of this story is that if you're stuck with this problem and don't know what to try next, try re-burning your boot .iso using software different than what was used initially.